Seeking Tools for Efficient Illustration Design in Physics Book Project
one of my friends intends to write a book related to the field of physics. I have been assigned to design illustrations similar to the images below for his book. The total number of these illustrations is about 150 (one hundred fifty).
I am familiar with tools like PowerPoint, Illustrator, and Photoshop. However, given the volume of work, I am looking for recommendations on tools that publishers use to increase efficiency and save time. If you know of any suitable tools for my work or have any experience in this area, please guide me !?




Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Photoshop and PowerPoint aren't suitable for work like this.   You need a vector image editor. If you already have Illustrator, use that. Alternative vector editors are CorelDraw, Affinity Designer, Inkscape.

All your examples are simple flat line drawings which contain  elementary 2D shapes + some texts. Illustrator is perfect for them. If you must draw 3D scenes you need also a CAD program. Illustrator can make some 3D shapes but they are separate items. If you need a scene where more than one 3D items are somehow interacting with each other or simply drawn to a certain geometric formation consistently, Illustrator is too poor - you really need a 3D CAD program.
150 illustrations sounds a big effort. But you collect soon a bunch of reusable items and that lightens the burden substantially.
An artist who doesn't understand the subject which he should illustrate  can do his job only if the author makes sketches which would be nearly perfect illustrations as is. If it happens that the author is not going to draw good sketches, he only describes loosely  what he wants and expects you build the actual image you also must have the knowledge and understanding of physics. Otherwise the case is hopeless.

Thank you, my friend.
